# array comparison(T) delegate NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, delegates, comparison, nullreferenceexception

I'm having a problem with the delegate not delegating... 
I have an object called Tweet that has a string text and an int score. I want to sort the array of tweet objects(twtArray) in order of the score. 
This is the code I have:

```
Array.Sort(twtArray, delegate(Tweet twt1, Tweet twt2)
        {
            return twt1.score.CompareTo(twt2.score); //(twt1.score - twt2.score)
        });
```

and it throws:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>           at System.Array.FunctorComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)

Whilst debugging, I noticed that the first comparison works but in the second comparison, `twt2` is null. And it can't be null because I definitely have 8 elements in the array.
I've tried reversing `twt1` and `twt2` as well but makes no difference. 
I also tried making my own comparison method in the Tweet class but again, same thing.
Any help would be appreciated!

Also, I dont think this is a duplicate of this question: [List.Sort in C#: comparer being called with null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026044/list-sort-in-c-comparer-being-called-with-null-object)
because i tried all the possible solutions from this but it's not working. i've also searched a lot on google :(

Comment: Even if you have an `Tweet[]` with 8 elements they can be null: `Tweet[] twtArray = new Tweet[8];`

Comment: I meant that the Tweet[] is of size 20 and I can see that there are 8 Tweet objects in there (with correct text and score values) in the first line of my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have a `Tweet[]` with 8 elements some can be `null`:

`Tweet[] twtArray = new Tweet[8]; // all instances are null`

You: *The Tweet[] is of size 20 and I can see that there are 8 Tweet objects in there (with correct text and score values) in the first line of my code.*

So the array's size is 20 but only 8 are initialized? (see above)
`Array.Sort` needs to compare all with all others.

You could prevent it in this way:

```
Array.Sort(twtArray, delegate(Tweet twt1, Tweet twt2)
{
    if(twt1 == null && twt2 == null) return 0;
    if(twt1 == null) return -1;
    if(twt2 == null) return  1;
    return twt1.score.CompareTo(twt2.score); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're working with an array that's only partially filled, that indicates that you don't actually want an array, you want `List<T>`.

Using that, you can have a collection that contains 8 items, but can be later expanded to 20 efficiently. And when you call `Sort()` on such list, you're not going to have any problems with `null`s.

Comment: how very true. a little embarrassed for not realising this earlier... :/